# Ftp freezes despite connection seems allright

Tags: ftp

I am trying to connect to a an ftp through command line using

```
ftp ftpperso.free.fr
```

I am then prompted for username and password.

I get this message

```
230 User username logged in.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
```

and `status` confirms that I am connected to the server.

However when I then try any command (ie. `ls`) the console freezes and nothing happens.

Do you have any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably behind a NAT, and therefore need to enable passive mode before doing anything.

```
ftp> passive
Passive mode on.
```

Comment: I'll try that tonight.
What is a NAT by the way?

Comment: `What is a NAT by the way?`   @AlfredM, [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). It lets you connect multiple devices to your Internet connection without having to give each one a (globally) unique IP address.